# How Can I enable rdp access to a laptop after it connects to VPN?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I connect to work's VPN on my laptop. I added a route but the moment my laptop is connected to work's VPN, I can no longer access it from my desktop. Here's the route I added:

```
route -p add 192.168.1.2 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.7 metric 1
```

**Laptop** is **192.168.1.7** and **Desktop** is **192.168.1.2**

### Output of Route Print is the following :

```
 
===========================================================================
Interface List
 36...........................VPN Secure Connection
 14...xx xx xx xx xx xx ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 12...xx xx xx xx xx xx ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
 11...xx xx xx xx xx xx ......Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.7     25
    2.255.255.254  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      10.21.12.94  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      10.21.12.95  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     10.21.12.104  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     10.21.12.105  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     10.21.12.156  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     10.21.12.157  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      10.79.199.6  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6    276
     10.79.249.67  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      10.100.44.8  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    10.115.68.110  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    10.115.68.112  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    10.134.202.15  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     10.156.34.68  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    139.71.65.141  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    139.71.65.143  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.171.49.34  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.171.49.35  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.171.49.73  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.171.49.74  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.49.102  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.49.103  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.49.201  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.49.205  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.49.238  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.52.126  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.52.200  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.171.53.48  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.53.101  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.172.3.179  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.172.79.88  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.172.124.22  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  148.172.134.233  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.173.129.25  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.173.129.82  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.173.133.19  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  148.173.165.105  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  148.173.250.141  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  148.173.250.202  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.173.251.64  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  148.173.251.205  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     164.12.33.56  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    281
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7     26
      192.168.1.6  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      192.168.1.7  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    281
     192.168.1.15  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     192.168.1.17  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.79.199.6    276
      224.0.0.252  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  239.255.255.250  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.7       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: What kind of VPN is it?  How did you create it?  Is split tunneling enabled?

Comment: The VPN software is called Aventail Connection with Smart Tunneling. It's version 10.5.3.54